# Second variation formula for minimal surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

I am reading the Colding and Miniczzi book "*A course in Minimal Surfaces*". 
In chapter 1, section 8 there is a derivation of the second variation formula, and the stability operator $L$, but just for the case of normal variations.

A normal vector fields $J$ on a minimal surface $\Sigma$ is said to be a *Jacobi field* if $LJ = 0$.

Then in the book they consider the case when $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the graph of a function satisfying the minimal surface equation. Then they consider the variation $F: \Sigma \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as:
$$
F \colon (x_1, x_2, x_3, t) \mapsto (x_1, x_2, x_3 + t).
$$
The variation field on the surface is $(0, 0, 1)$ and clearly 
$$
t \mapsto Vol\big(F(\Sigma, t) \big) 
$$
is constant.

Then in the book they conclude that the **normal component of the variation field of this variation is a Jacobi Field**.

I don't understand why this should be true. I mean, how can we assert that the normal component of the variation $F$ does not change the volume? In principle this could be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only interested in geometry (and not parametrization), then the normal component of a variation field is the only part that matters - any field can be written as the sum of a tangential part and a normal part, and variations of a map tangential to its image do not change its image.

Thus, the variation generated by the normal component of $(0,0,1)$ will have image coinciding with that of $F$, which clearly has constant volume.

Comment: Yes thanks! I actually just realized that it was a silly question. 
Because the first variation formula is:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} Vol(F(\Sigma, t)) = - \int_\Sigma (F_t, H)
$$
where F is a variation (not necessarily normal) with compact support. 
And since the mean curvature vector $H$ is normal, it's clear that the tangent component of the variation does not contribute. 

Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is one technical detail @Onil90, the variation $F$ (the translation) is not of compact support, so for your first variation formula, there would be a boundary term.

Comment: @JohnMa you are right. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In fact you can just calculate $L f$, where $f = \vec n \cdot (0,0,1)$ is the orthogonal part of $(0,0,1)$ and check that to be zero. Of course it is not so geometric. @Onil90

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, right, but it would be nice to avoid the computation.. :D mmmh